# Regex in RequestParser for Python Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, get, guzzle, flask-restful

Wondering if it's possible in [Python Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/), to use regular expressions while [parsing arguments](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html)?

For example, per the [documentation for multiple values](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#multiple-values-lists), I have the following argument I'm expecting in our API:

```
parser.add_argument('fq', type=str, action='append', help='expecting filter query (fq) (multiple)')
```

As is evident in the description and parameters, this field can repeat.  Unfortunately, I'm working with PHP libraries (namely, [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) via [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)) that return repeating values in the following form:

```
?fq[0]=foo&fq[1]=bar&fq[2]=baz
```

With an unknown number of `fq` parameters to parse, it would be invaluable to be able to define a regex parser, something akin to:

```
parser.add_argument('(fq)\[[0-9]+\]', type=str, action='append', help='expecting filter query (fq) (multiple)')
```

that would capture anything in the form `fq[#]`, drop the brackted `[]` suffix, and append all those to an `fq` list in the `args` dictionary.

Is that possible with Flask-RESTful?  I'm not seeing anything in the documentation, save some comments about potentially moving to something like Marshmallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code to check input for regex:

```
from flask_restful import inputs
...
.....
parser.add_argument('fq', type=inputs.regex('^[0-9]+$'), action='append', help='expecting filter query (fq) (multiple)')
```

Comment: but why every time the input is not fulfilled the regex, this text `Value does not match pattern: $regex_pattern` appear right after the help text we made.